# Create Groupby Column Based on Rank Conditions Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with an events database in python, and I need to write a function to quantify if a specific event follows (AT ANY POINT) another specific event.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
               'Product':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
               'Updated_At':['2015-01-01',
                             '2015-02-01',
                             '2015-03-01',
                             '2015-04-01',
                             '2015-05-01',
                             '2015-06-01'],
                   'Event':[1,1,2,1,3,2]})
```

For each product a user has, does event 2 AT ANY POINT follow event 1 before the next occurrence of event 1. If yes, keep row where event = 1.

The answer ('Event_Updated' contains the rows I would like to keep):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
               'Product':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
               'Updated_At':['2015-01-01',
                             '2015-02-01',
                             '2015-03-01',
                             '2015-04-01',
                             '2015-05-01',
                             '2015-06-01'],
               'Event':[1,1,2,1,3,2],
               'Updated_Event':['no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']})
```

Logical step seems to be to keep using groupby(['User','Product']) and create a dummy column to add to the groupby, then check if, in each instance of User,Product,EventType1 there also exists a row where Event = 2. Something like the 'Event_Dummy' column below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
               'Product':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
               'Updated_At':['2015-01-01',
                             '2015-02-01',
                             '2015-03-01',
                             '2015-04-01',
                             '2015-05-01',
                             '2015-06-01'],
               'Event':[1,1,2,1,3,2],
               'Event_Dummy': [1,2,2,3,3,3],
               'Updated_Event':['no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']})
```

Then the statement would be somehting along the lines of:

check if `df.grouby('User','Product','Event_Dummy')` contains `2`.

Please let me know how I can help clarify the question.

Comment: I think I dont understand. Do you wan create column `Updated_Event`? Or something else? I dont understand in column `Updated_Event` second `yes`. First `yes` is because it is second occurrence, or not? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Yes, I want to create the column 'Updated_Event'. Updated_event should only evaluate to true if the 'Event' = 1, and that event is followed at some point by 'Event' = 2 (before another Event=1). The first 'yes' is so because the Event is followed by Event 2. The second 'yes' is so because the event is followed by Event 2 (even though it is not directly after the Event=1)